# vbscript code gives logon denied error when connecting to Oracle DB with AD id

Tags: oracle, vbscript, oracle11g

I am using the following connection string to connect to a particular oracle db in vbscript.

```
strCon="Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=server_name)(PORT = port_number))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=service_name)));Uid=ad_id;Pwd=P@$$w0rd;"
Set objDBConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objDBConnection.Open strCon
```

I get the below error:

[Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle][Oracle]ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

The above connection string works without any error when i use generic username and password. But i get ORA-01017 error when i use my ad id and password to connect.

Is there any particular way to connect using ad id and password.

Comment: Why do you think oracle knows your AD login?  That has to be configured. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b32010/active_dir.htm#CDEJFFGI

Comment: Thank you for the response.
That is taken care of and with the ad id and password i m able to login from sql developer.

Comment: When using windows authentication, you do not provide login and password. It is used inherently. Take the login/password attributes out and see if it works. Try just `userid=/` and see if it works

Comment: Yeah.. try just `Uid=/;` at the end or remove Uid and Pwd completely